# insert many rows, LAST_INSERT_ID return 1

Tags: mysql, sql, last-insert-id

Have:

```
1. create DB
2. create Table
3. insert 3 rows
4. select LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Here test code:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS TEST;
CREATE DATABASE TEST;
USE TEST;
CREATE TABLE test (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        age INT
    );

INSERT INTO test (age) VALUES (1), (2), (3);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Why LAST_INSERT_ID() return 1 ?
Excepted: 3

How to get valid LAST_INSERT_ID() ?

Comment: mysql Server version: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) clearly explains this behavior:

> With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value representing the **first** (emphasis mine) automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement. The value of LAST_INSERT_ID() remains unchanged if no rows are successfully inserted.

The first value generated by the auto increment sequence in the insert was 1, not 2 or 3, so the value 1 gets returned.

I think the confusion you have is around the name `LAST_INSERT_ID`.  The "last" part refers to the most recent insert *statement*, not the most recent `id` value within that insert.